# R: Inserir diferença de data em uma função para diferença de horário

Tags: r, funções, diff

Encontrei uma função feita por J.Ahumada e achei super interessante, tudo a ver com meu trabalho. A função é para separar registros fotográficos de uma espécie em uma determinada unidade amostral(ua) a partir de um intervalos de independência desejado.

Criei um objeto com as informações de uma determinada espécie em uma única unidade amostral. O objeto chama-se "paca".

```
paca <- filter(meus.dados, ua==" GF", data, hora, especie=="Cuniculus paca")
paca

     ua       data     hora        especie
   (chr)     (time)    (chr)          (chr)
1     GF 2012-06-02 01:12:00 Cuniculus paca
2     GF 2012-06-11 23:50:00 Cuniculus paca
3     GF 2012-06-12 00:06:00 Cuniculus paca
4     GF 2012-06-12 01:16:00 Cuniculus paca
5     GF 2012-07-11 20:35:00 Cuniculus paca
6     GF 2012-07-24 23:52:00 Cuniculus paca
7     GF 2012-08-01 21:39:00 Cuniculus paca
8     GF 2012-08-09 02:37:00 Cuniculus paca
9     GF 2012-08-11 00:24:00 Cuniculus paca
10    GF 2012-08-13 00:55:00 Cuniculus paca
11    GF 2012-08-13 19:47:00 Cuniculus paca
12    GF 2012-08-15 19:16:00 Cuniculus paca
13    GF 2012-08-18 02:35:00 Cuniculus paca
14    GF 2012-08-18 22:28:00 Cuniculus paca
15    GF 2012-08-24 02:27:00 Cuniculus paca
```

Ao rodar a função, retorna a sequência de números correspondente ao número da linha criada pelo R (1 a 15). E quando o registro não respeita o intervalo de 60min ele repete o número da linha onde está o registro.

```
reg.independentes<-function(dados,independencia){

   l<-length(dados$data)
   intervalo<-diff(dados$data)
   intervalo<-intervalo/60 #informar intervalo de independência em minutos
   intervalo<-as.numeric(intervalo)
   ev<-1;res<-numeric()
   cond<-intervalo> independencia 
   for(i in 1:(l-1)){
   if(!cond[i]) ev<-ev
   else ev<-ev+1
   res<-c(res,ev)

   }
  c(1,res)
 }

 reg.independentes(paca, 60)
 [1]  1  2  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  9 10 11 11 12 12 13 14 15
```

A função não considera o  fato do registro ter sido em datas diferentes, está considerando apenas o horário. Gerando duas situações:

Primeira: repetindo linhas onde o registro foi na mesma data,porém com intervalos maior que 60min. Por exemplo, ele repete a linha 3,  ao conferir os registros, eles possuem intervalo maior que 60min, conforme o desejado (data é igual e horário diferente - 00:06 e 01:16). Não entendi o por que, não era para este registro estar sendo sinalizado!!

Segunda: repetindo linhas onde o registro é em datas diferentes apenas do horário ser semelhante. A função não está considerando a questão da data ser diferente,por exemplo, sinalizou a linha (9, 11 e 12) porém os registros são em datas diferentes, tornando-se independente.

O registro é considerado Não Independente se ocorrer no mesmo dia e em intervalo menor que 60min. Se o registro for em horários semelhantes, mas em datas diferentes são considerados Independentes (isso que eu preciso que a função faça)

Tentei alterar a fórmula da função mas não estou conseguindo. Gostaria de acrescentar que a função retornasse uma tabela com apenas os registros independentes.... Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: bem, vamos tentar, para isso preciso compreender melhor em código:
primeiro, o que voce quiz dizer com conjunto de dados, ou seja, é um array?
segundo, pressupondo que esse seu "conjunto de dados" seja um array eu faria a comparação dos valores separando cada item com split(cjdados[index]) e como eu sei qual coluna do array que a funçao split me retorna que quero, no caso a data e hora e compararia esses valores diretamente dentro da funçao

Comment: Me expressei mal. Conjunto de dados seria as informações da espécie que armazenei em um objeto, que chamei de "paca" .

Comment: ainda tah confuso, esse objeto retorna o que, uma lista json, uma string ou algo do tipo com os valores que são passados para a function como parametros? para poder comparar o valor pela forma que expus voce precisa saber isso para poder percorrer essa lista (dados) e comparar os valores, é moleza com um array.

Comment: vixe, eu sou programador Java, python e PHP, em excel sem chance pra mim, mil desculpas!

Comment: Eu estou iniciando no R. Os meus dados estão todos em planilha Excel, então, leio e começo a trabalhar em cima.  Mas, mto obrigada pela pela atenção.

Comment: quase nunca uso o excell pra nada, mas se vc for programar isso nessas linguagens que te falei, disponha, "mato a pau" em 2 palitos!

Comment: deve ter sim, vb acho eu, nunca uso excel, mas em java por ex, eu colocaria esses "dados" em um array separado e percorreria ele na function para separar cada linha em um outro array usando algo tipo `if (linha[i].split()[2].equals('00:60')){ return 'independente';}`
e por ai vai.

Comment: Hum, vou tentar. Alguém sugere outra forma? Tenho uma planilha com dados de 4 anos, em várias ua diferentes com registros fotográficos em data e horário distintos para espécies diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trabalhar com funções criadas por outras pessoas não é muito simples (especialmente sem a explicação do algoritmo), então achei mais simples fazer do zero.

Em primeiro lugar, é importante você transformar seus dados para um formato de tempo que o R entenda, para simplificar a medição do intervalo. Seu paste dos dados mostram que as data estão como `time`, mas a hora não. Como comecei a partir de tudo em formato de texto, a forma seria a seguinte:

```
paca <- read.table(text = "ua       data     hora        especie
     GF 2012-06-02 01:12:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-06-11 23:50:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-06-12 00:06:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-06-12 01:16:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-07-11 20:35:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-07-24 23:52:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-08-01 21:39:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-08-09 02:37:00 Cuniculus_paca
     GF 2012-08-11 00:24:00 Cuniculus_paca
    GF 2012-08-13 00:55:00 Cuniculus_paca
    GF 2012-08-13 19:47:00 Cuniculus_paca
    GF 2012-08-15 19:16:00 Cuniculus_paca
    GF 2012-08-18 02:35:00 Cuniculus_paca
    GF 2012-08-18 22:28:00 Cuniculus_paca
    GF 2012-08-24 02:27:00 Cuniculus_paca", 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

paca$data_completa <- strptime(paste(paca$data, paca$hora),
                              format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Juntei as informações de data e hora em uma única string e usei a função `as.Date` para transformar em formato de data.

Para duplicar o índice das medições que seguem seu critério, precisamos apenas verificar quais intervalos são menores que o limite (no caso, 60 minutos), e repetir estas posições. A função final fica assim:

```
reg_independentes <- function(dados, independencia) {
  intervalo <- diff(dados) #Apenas a informação de tempo é necessária. A função diff calcula o intervalo entre o valor e o seu valor anterior. 
  units(intervalo) <- "mins" # Precisamos disso para garantir que faremos a comparação em minutos, sempre.
  repetir <- which(intervalo < independencia) # Verifcamos quais intervalos são menores que o valor independencia.
  sort(c(0, seq_along(intervalo), repetir)+1) # Juntamos os valores por ordem crescente. Precisamos do 0 e do + 1 porque sempre há um intervalo a menos que o número de valores.
}
```

Utilizando a função:

```
reg_independentes(paca$data_completa, 60)
# [1]  1  2  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Acho que o resultado agora está correto, mas se não estiver você deve conseguir fazer o ajuste necessário.